# Can't create a new Rails project due to gem and bundle install errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm following this tutorial on ruby on rails(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fmyvWz5TUWg), and at 22:16 he creates a new project with "rails new friends". When I tried to do that, some files are created then the following errors occur below:

```
Fetching puma 5.6.2
Installing bindex 0.8.1 with native extensions
Installing sqlite3 1.4.2 with native extensions
Installing msgpack 1.4.5 with native extensions
Installing puma 5.6.2 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bindex-0.8.1/ext/skiptrace
C:/Ruby31-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0 -r
./siteconf20220311-6336-mx8y4n.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory:
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bindex-0.8.1/ext/skiptrace
make DESTDIR\= clean
bash.exe: warning: could not find /tmp, please create!

current directory:
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bindex-0.8.1/ext/skiptrace
make DESTDIR\=
generating cruby-x64-mingw-ucrt.def
bash.exe: warning: could not find /tmp, please create!
compiling cruby.c
make: gcc: No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:246: cruby.o] エラー 127

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bindex-0.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.1.0/bindex-0.8.1/gem_make.out

  C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:95:in `run'
  C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:44:in `block in make'
  C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:36:in `each'
  C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:36:in `make'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:63:in `block in
build'
  C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tempfile.rb:317:in `open'
  C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:26:in `build'
  C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:161:in `build_extension'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `block in
build_extensions'
  C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:192:in `each'
  C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:192:in `build_extensions'
  C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/installer.rb:853:in `build_extensions'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:71:in
`build_extensions'
  C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:28:in `install'
  C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:204:in `install'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:54:in
`install'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:16:in
`install_from_spec'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:186:in
`do_install'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:177:in
`block in worker_pool'
  C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/worker.rb:62:in `apply_func'
  C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/worker.rb:57:in `block in process_queue'
  C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `loop'
  C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `process_queue'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/worker.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in
create_threads'

An error occurred while installing bindex (0.8.1), and Bundler cannot continue.

In Gemfile:
  web-console was resolved to 4.2.0, which depends on
    bindex
         run  bundle binstubs bundler
Could not find gem 'sqlite3 (~> 1.4)' in locally installed gems.
       rails  importmap:install
Could not find gem 'sqlite3 (~> 1.4)' in locally installed gems.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
       rails  turbo:install stimulus:install
Could not find gem 'sqlite3 (~> 1.4)' in locally installed gems.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I have tried:

```
$ bundle config build.puma --with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"
```

and

```
gem install puma -v '4.3.0' -- --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include --with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"
```

and still the same error occurs!
Any suggestions on what I should do or how I can fix this?

Answer (score -1):

Try running this:

`bundle config set --global build.puma --with-cflags=-fms-extensions`

& then run bundle install again

Comment: Can you edit and explain why this should work?